# PHPUnit not found

Tags: php, phpunit

I have encountered strange error.

```
$ phpunit
PHPUnit not found.
```

I installed the phpunit with the following command.

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
$ chmod +x phpunit.phar
$ sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Strangely, I can successfully run it's full path.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 4.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [options] <directory>
....
```

I tried this.

```
$ which phpunit
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

And, Successed with root user.

```
$ su
# phpunit
PHPUnit 4.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [options] <directory>
....
```

And, Deleted phpunit...

```
# rm /usr/local/bin/phpunit
# phpunit
# bash: phpunit: command not found

# su - admin
$ phpunit
PHPUnit not found.
$ which phpunit
/usr/bin/which: no phpunit in (/home/admin/.nvm/v0.10.17/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/admin/bin:/home/admin/sdxcmd.)
```

The server infomation.

- CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
- PHP 5.5.21 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2015 15:35:14)
- Installed php whis yum from remi repos.
- Previously, I was using the PHP I have installed from source.

Do you have any idea to fix this situation?

Comment: um... you've removed phpunit, and now wondering why it's not working? "I drove my car off a cliff and it's a twisted pile of wreckage at the bottom of the ravine. Why is it not parked in my driveway anymore?"

Comment: Missing phpunit before remove it...

Answer (score 1):

Try `echo $PATH` as normal user and as root. I suspect for root it will contain `/usr/local/bin`, for your current user, it will not.

If this is the case, see **[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)** for how to add it to your path.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`cd /usr/local/bin`
`sudo mv phpunit /usr/bin`
Move phpunit to `/usr/bin`